# <h:commandButton image="..." /> not rendered properly when specifying JSF resource name

Tags: image, jsf, resources, jsf-2.2, commandbutton

I've learned that JSF 2.2 has some special resources mechanism that loads images from the predefined *resources/* folder within my web application. That works quite well with an image like this:

```
<h:graphicImage name="gfx/Logos/Logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" styleClass="logo" />
```

The resulting `src="..."` translates to `/context/javax.faces.resource/gfx/Logos/Logo.png.xhtml` as expected.

I'd have thought that the same works with `<h:commandButton image="..." />` – but that's not true. The resulting `src="..."` attribute is not translated properly.

How can I fix this? Do I really have to use a CSS background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [tag documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandButton.html), the `<h:commandButton image>` takes a (relative) URL, not a JSF resource name.

Use the resource mapper in EL instead via `#{resource['library:name']}`. It'll convert a JSF resource identifier to a concrete URL.

```
<h:commandButton ... image="#{resource['gfx/Logos/Logo.png']}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that thing generates a HTML `<input type="image">` element which is intented as an image map which can capture mouse pointer coordinates on click. You seem to be more interested in a clickable image. In that case, better use `<h:commandLink><h:graphicImage>`.

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <h:graphicImage name="gfx/Logos/Logo.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```

#### See also:

- [Change the image of a JSF commandbutton with DHTML event onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285613/change-the-image-of-a-jsf-commandbutton-with-dhtml-event-onmouseover/7285664#7285664)

Comment: AH... the same as within CSS... understood. Thanks!